# Check a certain section of any string for certain characters, then move those certain characters to a different part of the string (Ruby 2.3.3)

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Given a string, what methods are available for checking a specific region of a given string for certain characters? For example, checking the first three characters of a string for vowels, or consonants.

Upon spotting those certain characters, what methods are available for moving those certain characters to different parts of the string?

My guess is to make the string into an array, use a method for selecting a certain portion of the array (Not just one spot--I want to select a range within the array), then checking said array against a few subcategories of characters. Given they match one of the categories of characters, I then want to know how I can move that *range* of characters to a different part of the string.

I know this is a bit vague, but that's how I need it. I've been googling it for hours, I'm not familiar enough with the terminology to properly google exactly what I'm looking for (or to even know if what I'm reading is what I'm looking for).

(Ruby 2.3.3)

Comment: Could you add a sample of input and expected output?

Comment: For instance, input string "aaabbbb" output string "bbaaabb". I need methods that allow me some flexibility in string manipulation.

Comment: Check the Ruby String [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html). There are methods to find a char index, substrings and so on.

Comment: I've added a second approach which is better because it references the original string's indices for insertion; please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**

You can employ [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) and [`insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-insert).

```
s = "aaabbbb"

range = 0..2
a, b = s.chars.partition.with_index { |_, i| range.include? i }
b.insert(2, *a).join #=> "bbaaabb"
```

This method references the false-partition `b` for insertion. If you'd rather reference the original string, do the following.

**Approach 2**

```
def paste(str, range, ins)
  ar = str.chars.map.with_index { |c, i| range.include?(i) ? nil : c }
  a = str[range]
  ar.insert(ins, *a).join
end

p paste 'aaabbbb', 0...3, -1 #=> "bbbbaaa"
p paste 'aaabbbb', 3...7, 0  #=> "bbbbaaa"
p paste 'aaabbbb', 2...3, 7  #=> "aabbbba"
```

---

**Steps for approach 1**

Select the range i.e. the characters you want to cut.

```
range = 0..2
```

Convert to an array of characters

```
p s.chars
 #=> ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"]
```

Partition the letters you want to keep `a` and those you don't `b` using parallel assignment.

```
s.chars.partition.with_index { |_, i| range.include? i }
 #=> [["a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b", "b"]]

#parallel assignment
a, b = [["a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b", "b"]]
p a #=> ["a", "a", "a"]
p b #=> ["b", "b", "b", "b"]
```

Leave `a` as it is, or map and reassign it into something else e.g., `a = a.map(&:upcase) #=> ["A", "A", "A"]`. Then insert `a` into `b` at the specified index before joining everything back up again.

```
p b.insert(2, *a).join
 #=> "bbaaabb"
```

**Notes**

We use `p` to inspect and print the various return values. If you're new to Ruby then there's a lot going on here, so don't expect to get everything right away- follow the steps carefully and read the [documentaion](http://www.ruby-doc.org). Steps for *approach 2* omitted but if you can follow *approach 1* okay, *approach 2* will be no problem.

Comment: When converting the string into an array, does the .chars suffice enough alone to make it into an array? The p, if I'm correct is used sort of like command.log is used in Javascript, would you say?

Comment: @TylerCurtisJowers Yes `chars` will suffice. Try it in irb:) `'he'.chars #=> ['h','e']`. Yes, I guess you can think of `p` as sort of like `console.log` from JavaScript. Thanks for the 'accept' but there's no rush to select at answer as 'accepted'. Usually it's best to wait a while to give others a chance!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
def movem(str, from_off, nbr, to_off)
  to_off -= [to_off-from_off, nbr].min if to_off > from_off
  (str[0, from_off] + str[from_off+nbr..-1]).insert(to_off, str[from_off,nbr])
end

str = "whaXXtchamacallit"
#      01234567890123456
from_off = 3
num = 2
```

Below I have varied `to_off` from zero to `str.size` (17) while keeping `str`, `from_off` and `nbr` to the values specified above.

```
(0..str.size).each { |i| puts "%2d: %s" % [i, movem(str, from_off, num, i)] }
 0: XXwhatchamacallit
 1: wXXhatchamacallit
 2: whXXatchamacallit
 3: whaXXtchamacallit
 4: whaXXtchamacallit
 5: whaXXtchamacallit
 6: whatXXchamacallit
 7: whatcXXhamacallit
 8: whatchXXamacallit
 9: whatchaXXmacallit
10: whatchamXXacallit
11: whatchamaXXcallit
12: whatchamacXXallit
13: whatchamacaXXllit
14: whatchamacalXXlit
15: whatchamacallXXit
16: whatchamacalliXXt
17: whatchamacallitXX
```